# OWIN OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider custom error response

Tags: c#, json, oauth, owin

For the current WebAPI, I use a custom implementation of the `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`.

I need to return a JSON response if the login has failed. This response is a simple `ViewModel` containing lockout time, etc. if any.

I Am however, unable to send the response. It either gets cut off at `25` characters (??) or sends it as an escaped C# `string` (`"\"lockout": 2"` etc.)

This is what i have tried so far:

```
context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
context.Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authResult));
```

Comment: Did you set the `Response.ContentLength` property?

Comment: Yes tried that, seems however to set it back to 25

Comment: I believe the OAuth provider is simply overriding your response (and in that case is appending to the same stream, but overriding the ContentLength header). Look at this answer, it may help you find a solution (the issue is the same): http://stackoverflow.com/a/36755639/3670737

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by storing the content length in the Request context (temporarily).

```
context.Request.Set("Content-Length", json.Length.ToString());
```

Then obtain it in the Startup.cs

```
if (c.Request.Environment.ContainsKey("Content-Length"))
{
    c.Response.ContentLength = Convert.ToInt64(c.Request.Environment["Content-Length"]);
    c.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    c.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;  
}
```